# Time complexity of radix sort

Tags: java, sorting, radix-sort

I read time complexity of radix sort is O(wn) or O(n log n), if all n numbers are distinct. After implementation it look to me as if I have implemented radix sort which has time complexity of O(n ^2). Please take a look at my implementation and suggest, if there is some implementation problem or my observation about time complexity is wrong.

**Please note: I have hard coded few values for simplicity to sort 3 digit numbers only.**

```
private void LSBSort(int[] arr) {
    _LSBSort(arr, 1);
}

private void _LSBSort(int[] arr, int divisor) {
    Deque[] deques = new Deque[10];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++) {
        int mod = (arr[i] /divisor ) % 10;
        if (deques[mod] == null) {
            deques[mod] = new ArrayDeque<>();
        }
        deques[mod].add(arr[i]);
    }
    divisor *= 10;
    if (divisor > 1000) {
        return;
    }

    int cursor = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
        if (deques[i] != null) {
            for (int j = 0 ; j <= deques[i].size() ; j++) {
                cursor = cursor + j;
                arr[cursor] = (int)deques[i].pollFirst();
            }
            cursor++;
        }
    }
    _LSBSort(arr, divisor);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the time complexity is O(n^2)? To me, it looks like each run of `_LSBSort` takes time O(n), and it is repeated w times.

Comment: Due to nested for loop in _LSBSort and if every deque is not null it will take O(n^2) time.

Comment: Remember that each item in the list is in exactly one of the deques -- thus iterating through all 10 deques is only iterating through n objects in total.

Comment: but one qeque can have more than one element and iterating each deque is proportional to its size.

Comment: Precisely. Say `deques[i]` contains si items, so iterating over it takes time O(si). Then the outer `for` loop takes time O(s1) + O(s2) ... + O(s10) = O(s1 + s2 + ... + s10). But since each item occurs in exactly one deque, we know s1 + s2 + ... + s10 = n. Conclude the loop takes time O(n).

Comment: Got it, thanks. Can you put this as an answer, so other can easily follow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**: the runtime is O(wn), as it should be for this algorithm.

Consider a single run of `_LSBSort`. Let n be the length of `arr`. Clearly the first loop is time O(n). Let si be the length of `deques[i]`. Then the second loop is time
$$ O(s_1) + O(s_2) + \dots + O(s_{10}) = O(s_1 + s_2 + \dots + s_{10}).$$
Noting that each element is present in exactly one of the deques, we conclude
$$s_1 + s_2 + \dots + s_{10} = n.$$
Thus the entire method runs in time O(n). As it is called w times, we conclude the entire algorithm is O(wn) time.

**Second**: some comments on the code.

1. These methods should be static.
2. Use an `ArrayList` for `deque`. Arrays of generics are just too ugly.
3. Call the list `deques` because it is plural.
4. Initialize all the deques up front. Clear and reuse between iterations.
5. Use extended for loops throughout.
6. Use loop instead of recursion.

```
private static void LSBSort(int[] arr) {
    List<ArrayDeque<Integer>> deques = new ArrayList<>(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        deques.add(new ArrayDeque<Integer>());
    }

    for (int d = 1; d <= 1000; d *= 10) {
        for(int i : arr) {
            deques.get((i / d) % 10).add(i);
        }

        int cursor = 0;
        for (Deque<Integer> D : deques) {
            for (Integer j : D) {
                arr[cursor++] = j;
            }

            D.clear();
        }
    }
}
```